# Weird font quality using book class

Tags: fonts, pdftex, books, lmodern

I compiled a book using this preamble

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.9}
```

The thing is that the font seems thin

125%:

[image]

800%:

[image]

compared to some other document

125%:

[image]

800%:

[image]

I tried adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` but it doesn't change anything. Also, the font type reported in the file properties of the pdf is "Type 1", is that an old type?

Comment: This seems like a viewer issue, which one are you using?

Comment: adobe acrobat pro dc

Comment: Do you see the issue also at higher resolution?

Comment: what you mean? I took the two screenshots at 125%

Comment: Open both documents side by side and magnify them on the screen as much as you can. Are there still differences then? If you have a printer: are there differences in the printout?

Comment: I added two other screenshots at 800%, is that ok?

Comment: The upper screenshot uses either Computer Modern or Latin Modern (a clone of Computer Modern), and the lower one uses (a clone of) Times (Roman). The glyphs of Computer Modern (a "modern" font) definitely look thinner than those of Times Roman. What's your question? Maybe, how to load Times Roman fonts? Please clarify.

Comment: My question is how to get a deeper font like the other one, also I just wanted to know if the preamble was causing any conflicts because I find the generated text difficult to read unless zoomed in a lot

Comment: Sounds to me you are just not happy with the default font? Take a look through the font catalogue https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ to find a font that has heavier weight. Click on the font and it will show you what to include in the preamble to get that font.